# Why my autoload.php of composer doesn't work?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, respect-validation

I have a project, I use Composer and i import many thing by it... i require the autoload.php in my index (the root of project) and istead Slim, Mongo, Twig work very well. But when I call a class of Respect/Validation it doens't work; if I simply use Respect/Validation the error is:

`Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in (path of file when i need it).`

if I try to require also here the autoload.php the errors are:

`**Warning**: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in (path of file when i need it)`

`**Fatal error**: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in (path of file when i need it)`

Comment: I have done it in Composer/bin by cmd... dir=$(d=$(dirname "$0"); cd "$d" $$ pwd) if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then dir=$(cygpath -m $dir); fi dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g') php "${dir}/composer.phar" $* –

Comment: Have you tried to include the file autoload.php in a relative way from where you need?

Comment: I tried it, and like I said, I said that autoload.php not find the file, but if I leave only the "use" tells me that tells me I can not find the Validator class.

Comment: You need to `require_once('../../../../vendor/autoload.php')`. In this way include the file you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using a file (`file.php`) in a particular directory like this:

```
/app/controller/validation
```

and your vendor directory is in the base path of the project, you need to include the relative path to vendor directory:

```
../../../vendor/autoload.php
```

Answer (score 24):

Try using `php composer dump-autoload`. It may fix that problem.

Answer (score 8):

I did this. 
i checked the file and permissions as always but everything looks ok. Then I open autoload.php and see ... oh! we have `__DIR__` ofcourse.

I was doing this

`require '../../vendor.autoload.php';`

Changed to

`require __DIR__.'../../vendor.autoload.php';`

Not politically correct but got me by the frustrating waste of time for the moment.

ofcourse there are better alternatives to `__DIR__` like using a BASE Path etc. But this worked for me.

Comment: 2016...also I moved to python. :P

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with xampp. I installed composer and used:

```
composer create-project --stability=dev --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic D:\xampp\htdocs\newapp
```

My issue solved now.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and i solved it by using the last version of laravel, just try this code to create your project:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel exampleProject --prefer-dist`

this always uses the last version.

Answer (score -1):

I solved simple re-run composer update from the project Root. 
(my case was on Magento2, but the error and the path are the same)

Answer (score -1):

In my case i simple forgot to change my working directory before running the command `composer require cboden/ratchet` in cmd this fixed it `cd c:\path to project\` then `composer require cboden/ratchet`