# Symfony2 deploy failure vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, symfony

I have deployed a **Symfony2** application to shared hosting server from local machine. I used a git pull followed by composer install and then i chmoded the `app/cache` and `app/logs` permissions to 777.

Each time I run the application I get the following error:

> [2016-02-06 18:55:43] request.CRITICAL:
>   Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException:
>   "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php')" at
>   /home/tdarlic/public_html/magniblu/users/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 5 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Compile
>   Error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') at /home/tdarlic/public_html/magniblu/users/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControll
>       er.php:5)"} []

I managed to fix this by entering full path to autoload.php:

```
require '/home/tdarlic/public_html/magniblu/users/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I tried with

```
../../../vendor/autoload.php
```

and with

```
../../vendor/autoload.php
require __DIR__.'../../vendor.autoload.php';
```

and still cannot figure out how to keep the autoload file link loading correctly on development machine and on the server.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Similar issue can be found on:
[Why my autoload.php of composer doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312707/why-my-autoload-php-of-composer-doesnt-work)

Comment: You have to execute `php composer.phar update` ... When you move folders or install the project on another device, the vendor autoload.php doesn't exist or the path is absolute (so wrong path if you move the folder)

Comment: Why do you require an autoload from the controller at very first place?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The code was copied by another developer so I thought there was a reason. After your post I've checked the rest of the class, removed autoloader and it works. I lost 3 hours on this.....