# Class validator not found in respect validation Lib

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, respect-validation

I'm new in composer but I could get `vendor`, `composer.lock` and `composer.json` from cmd then I paste them to my project without Validation_Master folder.
My project Path: `C:\wamp64\www\php Projects\project 1\(here there are test.php and vendor, composer.lock and composer.json)`
Validation_Master folder path: `C:\wamp64\www\php Projects\Validation_Master`
My Code is:

```
<?php
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
    $number = 123;
    v::numeric()->validate($number);
?>
```

But the above code gives me the following error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\php Projects\project 1\test.php

---

What did I do?!!?
copy Validation_Master folder to the path of test.php ==> (Failed )
copy Vendor folder to the path of Validation_Master folder and required from there ==> (Failed )
Manipulate namespace a lot and add namespace Respect\Validation to the code ==> (Failed )
What's The PROBLEM ????
How Can I use Respect Validation Library ????? Please answer me basically (I read docs before but didn't help)
[vendor folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOoJU.jpg)
`composer.json` code:

```
{
    "name": "respect/validation",
    "description": "The most awesome validation engine ever created for PHP",
    "keywords": ["respect", "validation", "validator"],
    "type": "library",
    "homepage": "http://respect.github.io/Validation/",
    "license": "BSD Style",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Respect/Validation Contributors",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/Respect/Validation/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2",
        "malkusch/bav": "~1.0",
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "^1.5",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.6.9",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.3"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-bcmath": "Arbitrary Precision Mathematics",
        "ext-mbstring": "Multibyte String Functions",
        "egulias/email-validator": "Strict (RFC compliant) email validation",
        "malkusch/bav": "German bank account validation",
        "symfony/validator": "Use Symfony validator through Respect\\Validation",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "Use Zend Framework validator through Respect\\Validation",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "Fix PSR2 and other coding style issues"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Respect\\Validation\\": "library/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Respect\\Validation\\": "tests/library/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./vendor/bin/phpunit"
    }
}
```

the `autoload.php` code :

```
<?php
require_once  __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit46e0d859a60be6f2acf30ed92a2228ad::getLoader();
```

I appreciate and sorry that I've written a lot

**UPDATE** : My problem like this post : [Why my autoload.php of composer doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312707/why-my-autoload-php-of-composer-doesnt-work), but it didn't help
I also run `composer dump-autoload` in cmd ==> (failed)

Comment: Add your composer.json file content and a screenshot of your vendor folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you copied the composer.json of the `respect/validation` library, and tried to use it as the composer.json for your project. This is a completely wrong approach.

Use this as your project composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "respect/validation": "^1.0"
  }
}
```

Then:

- run `composer install`,
- run your script again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was really stupid that I did LOL, But why programmers put composer.json in the Lib when it doesn't work. what is the difference? Thank you alcohol again

Comment: Each lib has their composer.json to declare their own dependencies. Composer gathers all of these when you run update (install without a lock file is also an update process basically). It needs to know all requirements and constraints of all libs, to resolve the correct versions it can/should install.