# Cannot find classes from Composer Dependency in PhpStorm

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm trying to use respect validations in my PhpStorm's project. This is my first time using a Composer dependency and I runned into some trouble.

This is my setup:

[image: Image of my PhpStorm setup]

I have it installed, but the the very first `use` line throws the exception:

> Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\api\private\verifyUser.php on line 7

What else do I have to do to make PHP find the library?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950734/class-validator-not-found-in-respect-validation-lib

Comment: TBH this error has nothing to do with PhpStorm -- it's PHP itself who complains not PhpStorm. But for the actual question -- did you load your composer's `autoload.php` that handles class autoloading?

Comment: I now added "require_once '..\..\..\vendor\autoload.php';" but I'm still getting the same.

Comment: Got that one fixed aswell. Added  "\__DIR__" before the path to make it work. Very confusing considering the IDE acts like I'm entering the correct path by showing me the folders of the directory I'm in.